# VS2013 Update 4 tells me to upgrade to Windows 8.1 to load my Windows Phone 8.0 project

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

Since installing VS2013 Update 4 I can't load any of my Windows Phone 8.0 projects.  I get told that I have to upgrade to my PC to Windows 8.1.  Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this isn't a supported configuration on Windows 7. Not sure how I even got into this state.